# Sorting a associative array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, sorting, ksort

I have an associative array of format

```
[Article_title_1] => Array
        (
            [description] => Trial
            [created] => date
        )
[Article_title_2] => Array
        (
            [description] => Trial
            [created] => date
        )
```

I want sort the array in alphabetical order(by title) where Article_title_2 is the title of the article.

I tried ksort. It does not work. I was trying to use cakephp's set sort, could not get it to work either.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `ksort` not working?

Comment: Why didn't ksort work for you?

Comment: Yes, what output is ksort giving you?

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? I can assure you that it most certainly does "work".

Comment: Show the code where you tried `ksort`

Comment: I cannot get ksort to work either! He ain't necessarily lying, the mighty `ksort` function could be broken!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ksort() will treat each of your keys as a string, so it will sort according to normal string ordering rules, and is case-sensitive. This means you could end up with:

```
Article_Title_12
Article_title_1
Article_title_10
Article_title_11
Article_title_2
Article_title_3
Article_title_4
Article_title_5
Article_title_6
Article_title_7
Article_title_8
Article_title_9
```

If this is your problem, then you will need to use [uksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) with a custom comparison function